# In Jmeter, how do you store variables dynamically during runtime and use them later?

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

So I couldn't find an answer to this yet.

In JMeter:

I have 2 controllers, 1 loop and 1 while controller.

In the loop I create several objects. The system I create objects in gives them each an ID.

I want to store these IDs and reuse them later in the while controller and iterate through them all to perform an action on them.

I don't want to save to file, because I find that messy. I would like to store them in variables using beanshell.

Who can help me with this challenge? :)

Answer (score 1):

All Beanshell test elements come with `vars` shorthand which stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance.

1. To store the variable: `vars.put("variable_name", "variable_value");`
2. To read the variable: `vars.get("variable_name");`

[image: Beanshell Variables Demo]

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) to learn more about using JMeter and Java APIs in from Beanshell test elements.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, I did json path extraction in my loop controller and then store them in an arraylist using beanshell.

Then I used a forEach controller to iterate through that list.

It's messy but the best option available!